# SQL Server - Move records to a different table using MERGE

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

The below code **moves** student records from `StudentsTable` to `HighSchoolersTable` if `IsHighSchoolStudent = 1`. Both tables have the same columns - StudentId nvarchar(50), subjectId nvarchar(50), and IsHighSchoolStudent (bit).

| StudentId | SubjectId | IsHighSchoolStudent |
| --- | --- | --- |
| abc | sub1 | 1 |
| def | sub2 | 0 |
| xyz | sub3 | 1 |

As a part of the **migration rules**, the code needs to be converted to a MERGE statement. (Yes, I know the dangers of using MERGE https://sqlblog.org/merge. I have fought with my boss about it but he won't budge). I can't figure out what to "MATCH ON" for the merge statement and where to add the `IsHighSchoolStudent = 1` condition.

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
    INSERT INTO HighSchoolersTable
    SELECT *
    FROM StudentsTable
    WHERE IsHighSchoolStudent = 1;
    
    DELETE FROM originalTable
    WHERE IsHighSchoolStudent = 1;
COMMIT;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I still don't understand why your boss needs this to be `MERGE`. If he wants it to be a single statement because that helps him sleep better at night for some reason, why not `DELETE ... OUTPUT INTO`?

```
DELETE dbo.StudentsTable 
  OUTPUT deleted.StudentId, deleted.SubjectId
  INTO dbo.HighSchoolersTable(StudentId, SubjectId)
  WHERE IsHighSchoolStudent = 1;
```

- Example [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=22bf8332468bc5afc0083008c923755b)

Insisting you use `MERGE` for this is like making you use a broom to sweep up milk.

Answer (score 0):

`MERGE` can do any combination of these things "simultaneously":

```
INSERT INTO tableX
UPDATE tableX
DELETE FROM tableX
```

It **cannot** modify two tables at once. It *cannot* do these "simultaneously":

```
INSERT INTO tableX
DELETE FROM tableY
```

So, you have to use `two` statements, one INSERT and one DELETE. Your original queries are fine. Using an `output ... into` clause to your delete could enable you to have better perfomance by using a join on a primary key instead of a where. Still, that table representing students, I doubt the table size is big enough to justify (even this little) extra work.

Of course, you can also use two `MERGE`s instead, but this is not just dangerous, it is stupid.

Comment: Thanks. Can you provide code please?

Comment: @ZuziMufu Code for what? Two separate MERGE statements? Do you think that's really what your boss wants?

Comment: Sorry, I won't provide such code. If an employer sees I did so, it could be grounds for not employing me.